# No puedo hacer el contador de este codigo en Python

Tags: python

Usted fue contratado por Electronic Arts, la empresa desarrolladora y distribuidora de juegos tales como Battlefield, Need for Speed, los Sims entre otros. Es su primer día y fue asignado al area de desarrollo del famoso simulador de futbol FIFA y le solicitan realizar el siguiente modo de juego para integrar en la próxima actualización del juego.

De un listado de trece ( 13 ) jugadores sacados del equipo ideal y representados por los caracteres separados por coma ( . , + , T , | , X , - , * , Y , W , ! , @ , # , $) se debe realizar un campeonato en el cual cada jugador debe seleccionar mínimo un (1) y máximo seis (6) cobradores de tiro penal y a su vez elegir el mismo rango de jugadores que serán porteros. La lista de jugadores seleccionados como cobradores no debe tener jugadores repetidos como tampoco la de porteros, sin embargo se puede seleccionar un jugador como cobrador y como portero sin ningún problema. Adicional se va a solicitar el nombre del equipo que el usuario le quiera asignar al team.

Una vez Obtenida la lista seleccionada por parte de los usuarios, cada cobrador debe empezar la tanda de penales cobrando a cada uno de los porteros seleccionados y para determinar quien anoto un tanto en cada ejecución, se obtendrá el valor Unicode de cada jugador y el que tenga mayor valor será el triunfador. Por tanto, si el código Unicode del cobrador es mayor que el del portero se le asignara un gol (\u00D8), en caso de que tengan igual valor se toma como empate (\u265E) y en caso de que su valor sea menor se toma como atajada(\u00A5).

Finalmente, la consola deberá mostrar, primero el resultado final de cada disparo representado por su respectivo carácter Unicode, en la segunda línea determinar si el nombre del equipo es palíndromo o no mediante un mensaje que diga “ES PALINDROMO” o “NO ES PALINDROMO” y en la última línea debe imprimirse un entero con la mayor cantidad de goles anotados por un o unos jugadores en su respectiva tanda de anotación.

```
cobradores=input("")
porteros=input("")
equipo=str(input(""))


#Contador y Unicode. ME HACE FALTA HACER BIEN EL CONTADOR DE LOS GOLES
cobradores=list(cobradores)
porteros=list(porteros)
goles=0
for cobrador in cobradores:
  total=goles
  if total > goles:
    goles==total
  goles=0
  for portero in porteros:
    if cobrador > portero:
      goles=goles+1
      print("\u00D8",end="")
    elif cobrador == portero:
      print("\u265E",end="")
    else:
      print("\u00A5", end="")
    
    
#palindromo    
equipo=equipo.lower()
equipo=equipo.strip()
equipo=equipo.replace(" ","")
equipo=equipo.replace("í","i")  

if str(equipo)== str(equipo)[::-1]:
  print("\nES PALINDROMO")
else:
  print("\nNO ES PALINDROMO")

print(total)

#LOS DATOS QUE PUEDE PASARLE SON LOS SIGUIENTES: input 1: *WT+$ input 2: *WT+$ input 3: amor a roma. DEBE ARROJARLE ËSTE RESULTADO. ♞¥¥¥ØØ♞ØØØØ¥♞ØØØ¥¥♞Ø¥¥¥¥♞    ES PALINDROMO    4
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes una confusión entre `total` y `goles` que no tiene ni pies ni cabeza.

Aclaremos:

- `total` es la cantidad de goles del mejor cobrador a la fecha. Este parte en cero al comienzo del programa.
- `goles` es la cantidad de goles del cobrador que examinamos ahora. Se pone a cero con cada nueva iteración.

*Código*

```
cobradores = list(cobradores)
porteros = list(porteros)
total = 0  # Goles del mejor cobrador
for cobrador in cobradores:
    goles = 0 # Goles del cobrador
    for portero in porteros:
        if cobrador > portero:
            goles += 1
            print("\u00D8", end="")
        elif cobrador == portero:
            print("\u265E", end="")
        else:
            print("\u00A5", end="")
    if goles > total:
        total = goles
```

Luego de confrontar al cobrador contra todos los porteros, vemos si sus `goles` superan el `total` del mejor a la fecha. En tal caso, actualizamos.

#### Demo

```
cobradores = "*WT+$"
porteros = "*WT+$"
equipo = "amor a roma"

# Contador y Unicode. ME HACE FALTA HACER BIEN EL CONTADOR DE LOS GOLES
cobradores = list(cobradores)
porteros = list(porteros)
total = 0  # Goles del mejor cobrador
for cobrador in cobradores:
    goles = 0 # Goles del cobrador
    for portero in porteros:
        if cobrador > portero:
            goles += 1
            print("\u00D8", end="")
        elif cobrador == portero:
            print("\u265E", end="")
        else:
            print("\u00A5", end="")
    if goles > total:
        total = goles

# palindromo
equipo = equipo.lower()
equipo = equipo.strip()
equipo = equipo.replace(" ", "")
equipo = equipo.replace("í", "i")

if str(equipo) == str(equipo)[::-1]:
    print("\nES PALINDROMO")
else:
    print("\nNO ES PALINDROMO")

print(total)
```

produce:

```
♞¥¥¥ØØ♞ØØØØ¥♞ØØØ¥¥♞Ø¥¥¥¥♞
ES PALINDROMO
4

Process finished with exit code 0
```